# C# MongoDB find in Array

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this query in mongodb:

```
db.getCollection('emails').find({"to.address": {$in:['email@domain.com']}})
```

I have to convert it into C# code. I've searched a lot already and nothing seems to fit my needs.

I even did an elem match:

```
MongoCursor<Email> csr = ConnectionHandler.Collection.Find(Query<Email>.ElemMatch(t => t.to(Query<Email.Address>).In(a => a.address, emails)));
```

This is what I've come up with in C# so far:

```
var emails = emailAddresses.Select(e => e.emailAddress);
MongoCursor<Email> csr = ConnectionHandler.Collection.Find(Query<Email>.EQ("to.address", (Query<Email.Address>.In()));
```

It's incomplete. and obviously not close to the right solution.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The answer is as simple as this:

```
var emails = new BsonArray(emailAddresses.Select(e => e.emailAddress));
MongoCursor<Email> csr = ConnectionHandler.Collection.Find(Query.In("to.address", emails));
```

Apparently, you can do a query without using a type, so instead of using this:

```
Query<Email>.EQ
```

you can actually just slap your query in like this:

```
Query.In("to.address", emails)
```

just as long as the variable you are storing it into is typed with the object that you want, as well as, the collection you are querying against. e.g.:

```
MongoCursor<Email> csr
```

Cheers!